# I passed a value but it still return 0

Tags: c#, generics

I passed a value to a class and then from that class pass it to another class and get the value.

I tried to Parse the value, but it still didn't work, I also try to use getters and setters

```
    public class Product
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
    public class Book : Product
    {
        public string Isbn { get; set; }
        public int Price2 { get; set; }
    }
    public class Check : Book
    {
        public int Num;
        public int Num2;
        public int Calculate(Book product) //This is important, I would like to keep practicing pass
        {
            Num = (product.Price);
            Num2 = product.Price2;
            Console.WriteLine(Num2);
            return Num + Num2;
        }
    }
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var num = new Book();
            var checkNum = num.Price = 10; //these is the values
            var checkNum2 = num.Price2 = 20;
            var result = new Check();
            var checkNum3 = result.Calculate(new Book());
            Console.WriteLine(checkNum3.Num);
        }
    }
```

I am expecting 30 as the result

Comment: `result.Calculate(new Book())` - you're passing a *new* book, which will have values of 0 for `Price` and `Price2`. I suspect you meant `result.Calculate(num)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Let's make what you have work

1. `Calculate` needs to get the book that has prices set.
2. `Calculate` returns the number, we don't need to use `.Num`.

```
var num = new Book();
var checkNum = num.Price = 10; //these is the values
var checkNum2 = num.Price2 = 20;
var result = new Check();
var checkNum3 = result.Calculate(num);
Console.WriteLine(checkNum3);
```

## Better names

If you use better names it would be easier to follow.

```
var book = new Book();
book.Price = 10; //these is the values
book.Price2 = 20;
var check = new Check();
var calculated = result.Calculate(book);
Console.WriteLine(calculated);
```

## Let's improve

### A. (Best?) `Check` is a calulator

```
public class Check  // Not a book
{
    public static int Calculate(Book book)
    {
        var p = book.Price;
        var p2 = book.Price2;
        var total = p + p2;

        Console.WriteLine(total);
        return total;
    }
}

(...)

var calculated = Check.Calculated(book); // no: new Check()
```

### B. If `Check` has a `Book`.

The `Check` does not *be* a `Book`, it can *have* it.

```
public class Product
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

public class Book : Product
{
    public string Isbn { get; set; }
    public int Price2 { get; set; }
}

public class Check
{
    private readonly Book book;
    public Check(Book book) 
    {
       this.book = book;  
    }
    public int Calculate() => book.Price + book.Price2;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var book = new Book();
        book.Price = 10;
        book.Price2 = 20;
        var check = new Check(book);

        Console.WriteLine(check .Calculate());
    }
}
```

## 3 C. If `Check` is a `Book`

If `Check` *is* a `Book` it needs to store `Price` and `Price2`. Please consider the following example.

```
public class Product
{
    public Product() { }
    public Product(string title, int price)
    {
        Title = title;
        Price = price;
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

public class Book : Product
{
    public Book(Book book) : base(book.Title, book.Price)
    {
        Isbn = book.Isbn;
        Price2 = book.Price2;
    }

    public Book() { }

    public string Isbn { get; set; }
    public int Price2 { get; set; }
}

public class Check : Book
{
    public Check(Book book) : base(book)
    {
        // This should really call Book's contrcutor
    }
    public int Calculate() => Price + Price2;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = new Book();
        b.Price = 10;
        b.Price2 = 20;
        var c = new Check(b);

        Console.WriteLine(c.Calculate());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your immediate question, you're passing a *new* `Book` to the `Calculate()` method, and it has a value of zero for `Price` and `Price2`.

I believe what you're looking at is this:

```
var num = new Book();
num.Price = 10; //these is the values
num.Price2 = 20;
var result = new Check();
var checkNum3 = result.Calculate(num);
```

Note that I've removed `checkNum` and `checkNum2` variables as they are redundant.

However, your code still has some problems.

It makes no sense to make `Check` a subclass of `Book`. It's usage seems to be sum the two prices, and for that it doesn't need to be a sub-class. It can stand on it's own. Furthermore, since it doesn't actually use the two prices for anything other than summing up the values, it doesn't even need to have the two int properties. It can be simplified as below:

```
public class Check
{
    public int Calculate(Book product)
    {
        var sum = product.Price + product.Price2;
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Finally, if you're only using the `Check` class to perform a calculation, it can actually be a `static` class so that you can call the method even without creating an instance of it.

```
public static class Check
{
    public static int Calculate(Book product)
    {
        var sum = product.Price + product.Price2;
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Now you can call it like so:

```
var num = new Book();
num.Price = 10;
num.Price2 = 20;
var checkNum3 = Check.Calculate(num);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This makes so much sense, I know the code is a little ugly, I just wanted to practice passing a class through a method. I really appreciate your input!

Answer (score -1):

```
    public class Product
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
    public class Book : Product
    {
        public string Isbn { get; set; }
        public int Price2 { get; set; }
    }
    public class Check : Book
    {

        public int Calculate(Book product) //This is important, I would like to keep practicing pass
        {
           return product.Price+product.Price2
        }
    }
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var num = new Book();
             num.Price = 10; 
             num.Price2 = 20;
            var result = new Check();

         Console.WriteLine(result.Calculate(num)); //pass num  not new book
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are frowned upon as they are not good answers. Please explain why the posted code fixes the problem.